# get email content into a string in php

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to get the body of an email into a string to do some processing, the script below gets the email but it can't get the content into a string. Any thoughts?
Cheers,
D

```
/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' .     imap_last_error());
/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {  
/* begin output var */
$output = '';  
/* put the newest emails on top */
rsort($emails);  
/* for every email... */
foreach($emails as $email_number) {
/* get information specific to this email */
$overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);    
/* output the email header information */    
$output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
$output.= '<span class="subject">subject'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
$output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
$output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
$output.= '</div>';    
/* output the email body */
$output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
$pos = strpos("FIND_THIS", $message);
if ($pos !== false) {
    print "found<br/>";
}
else {
    print " not found <br/>";
}
}  
 echo $output;
} 
/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
```

Comment: So what is in `$output`? *Not* the contents of `$message`? As my understanding of `imap_fetchbody` goes, `$message` contains the body..

Comment: output is everything concatenated, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a 'section 2' in that particular email? If it's a plaintext email, there'll only be a 0 (headers) and 1 (body). The content sections are detailed here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php#89002

Comment: Thats correct it should be one, was trying all sorts to get it working. What i was getting confused with was finding if the string exists - had needle -> haystack instead of haystack -> needle ($pos = strpos("FIND_THIS", $message) should be $pos = strpos($message, "FIND_THIS")). School boy error! cheers guys